# Google asistant keeps playing sounds

Tags: google-assistant

My google assistant keeps playing sounds even when th screen is off, the sound is the same as when it proposes to speak to the microphone. But I can't stop it, even after the screen is off.
So I need a simple solution, I know I can stop he application by forcing stop, but I relly prefer to do it by app settings if possible, just becouse if I open the app again the problem starts again, and I use this app often, so It's anoying.
I'm on Galaxy A10 running android 9.0

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the Assistant, you can:

1. Open Google app
2. Select More -> Settings -> Google Assistant
3. Choose Assistant tab -> Phone and turn off "Google Assistant" switch

This should disable the Assistant and let the rest of Google app still work fine.